# Set CachePath in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have set up CefSharp and built with a embedded URL using the help of [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Step-of). But I do not know how to set the `CachePath` properly. There are about 12 modules in the project. I want my cache files to be persisted and when next time user loads the browser it should not take much time.

Answer (score 4):

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var newsettings = new BrowserSettings();

    CefSettings Settings = new CefSettings();
    Settings.CachePath = "test";  //always set the cachePath, else this wont work

    //add an if statement to initialize the settings once. else the app is going to crash
     if (CefSharp.Cef.IsInitialized == false)
         CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(Settings);

    var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

     toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For an example of setting `CachePath` see here:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/v39.0.2/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L32

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code.

```
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var newsettings = new BrowserSettings();

        CefSettings Settings = new CefSettings();
        Settings.CachePath = "";

        Cef.Initialize(Settings);

        var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(TestUrl);

        panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
```